# Resize array to specified length and evenly distribute value of indexes

Tags: javascript

I am very bad at math, so forgive me if this is super obvious, I did do research and couldn't find anything matching what I need.

I'm trying to make my audio analyser responsive in width. This has proven to be very difficult, as the [frequency array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/frequencyBinCount) has a fixed size.

By calculating the width of each bar, and against the width of the canvas, I can easily find out how many bars could fit inside it.

So let's say the canvas is 20 pixels wide, and each bar is 4 pixels wide (including space between). That would mean 5 bars could fit inside the canvas. So using this information, we could create a function that resizes the frequency array length to 5, and evenly distributes frequencies into those 5 indexes.

This way no frequency range is left out, and the analyser can be resized to any width, and still fill the space.

```
function resize(array, integer) {
    ...
    return result;
}

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5... 100] // Array that goes from 1 to 100 (100 indexes)

resize(array, 10) // [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

Here's the original array displayed on the canvas (the dotted bars are the ones that are outside of the canvas)

[image]

Now I want to resize the array so that the bars fit in the canvas like this (20 bars in this example)

[image]

I really hope I explained myself well here, this was very difficult to explain

Comment: 1 ... 100 are 100 indices.

Comment: @NinaScholz Whoops, that's a typo. Fixed.

Comment: now resize should return `[1, 11, 21, ... 81, 91]`, because the range is 10. and it starts with `1`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes I know. See my edit, I added that if you want to know how the algorithm would work, think about how an image is resized, each pixel is evenly distributed, I want to do that with these indexes.

Comment: i still do not understand. i see the image, but i do not know which data you need. i think you need an array with indices which points to the original array with the 1024 values. if you need only 20 values out of the 1024 values, the you have to take every 52(point 2)nd value of the original array.

Comment: @NinaScholz The frequency array is an array containing 1024 indices, each indice representing a value, the value is the height of the bar for the given frequency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109053/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-sebastian-olsen).

Answer (score 0):

This solution works. Now. With returning the nth value `factor` of the original array.

```js
function arrayResize(array, integer) {
    var factor =  array.length / integer;

    return Array.apply(null, { length: integer }).map(function (_, i) {
        return array[Math.floor(i * factor)];
    });
}

var array = Array.apply(null, { length: 100 }).map(function (_, i) { return Math.floor(i / 10); });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arrayResize(array, 5), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arrayResize(array, 10), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arrayResize(array, 20), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, http://i.imgur.com/gOcC7IX.png. It's just trimming the array down to 100 indices starting from 0. I ran `arrayResize(fbc_array, 100);`

Comment: sorry, cannot help, need more examples of the wanted result

Comment: I am creating a visual representation, give me a sec.

Comment: I've added illustrations.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen, do you find my answer now not anymore usefull?

Comment: The method doesn't work for arrays that are smaller than the specified size, causing blockyness to appear. It seems that in my case I do need to resize an array that is smaller than specified length. Your answer also is very outdated and uses old practices, which is irrelevant but I felt it was worth mentioning.

Comment: it is three years old, what do you expect?

Comment: It's three years old, but I needed this now only to find out that the solution does not work for arrays smaller than the desired length, so technically the answer is incorrect and therefore I decided to unaccept it.